# How to change page number and keep url argument?

Tags: php, regex

I want to change a number in my URL, this number is the page number, but I want to keep all other argument in the same url.

My exemple url is :

```
/index.php?page=wallrank-top10-2&requete=keyword&searchkeyword=pvp
```

My goal is to have :

```
/index.php?page=wallrank-top10-1&requete=keyword&searchkeyword=pvp
```

and

```
/index.php?page=wallrank-top10-3&requete=keyword&searchkeyword=pvp
```

So how I can do it in php ?

```
<?php
urlprec = currenturl -1;
urlnext = currenturl +1;
?>
```

I want to be able to change only "-1" by "-2"

How I can do it with php ?
perhaps with some regex or other simple method ?

Thanks

Comment: So you have `currenturl = '/index.php?page=wallrank-top10-1&...';` and you want `urlprec == '/index.php?page-wallrank-top10-0&...' && urlnext == '/index.php?page-wallrank-top10-2&...'`?

Comment: yes that's exactly what I want :)

Comment: I think 'pagination' is the [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+pagination) term you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know php. I can only tell you what you can do.

Use this regex:

```
(?!.*-)\d+
```

and replace the match by incrementing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$currenturl = '/index.php?page=wallrank-top10-2&requete=keyword&searchkeyword=pvp';
$_GET['page'] = 'wallrank-top10-2';

$currpage = explode('-', $_GET['page']);
print_r($currpage);
$urlprec = str_replace($_GET['page'],
                       implode('-', array_merge(array_slice($currpage, 0, -1),
                                                array(end($currpage)-1))),
                       $currenturl);
$urlnext = str_replace($_GET['page'],
                       implode('-', array_merge(array_slice($currpage, 0, -1),
                                                array(end($currpage)+1))),
                       $currenturl);
print $urlprec."\n";
print $urlnext."\n";

# or using regex

$urlprec = preg_replace_callback(
    '/page=([^&]+)-(\d)&/',
    function($matches) {
        return 'page='.$matches[1].'-'.($matches[2]-1).'&';
    },
    $currenturl);
$urlnext = preg_replace_callback(
    '/page=([^&]+)-(\d)&/',
    function($matches) {
        return 'page='.$matches[1].'-'.($matches[2]+1).'&';
    },
    $currenturl);

print $urlprec."\n";
print $urlnext."\n";
```

This will do what you asked, but doesn't take the first page and last page cases into account.

Comment: This one work perfectly for "urlprec" =>

$currenturl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$currpage = explode('-', $_GET['page']);
$urlprec = str_replace(''.$_GET['page'],
                       implode('-', array_merge(array_splice($currpage, 0, -1),
                                                array(intval($currpage[0])-1))),
                       $currenturl);

Comment: But for the "urlnext" that's nok fonctionnal
$urlnext = str_replace(''.$_GET['page'],
                       implode('-', array_merge(array_splice($currpage, 0, -1),
                                                array(intval($currpage[0])+1))),
                       $currenturl);

Comment: @WolwxAliasXavierRedondo oops too much Python coding I guess.. Fixed it.

Comment: I tried with your code, but to keep correct my url I must delete the 'page=' part, because that's removed it

Comment: after this, the $urlprec is ok, but that's still problematic with $urlnext, that's give =>
/index.php?page=4&requete=keyword&searchkeyword=pvp

Comment: @WolwxAliasXavierRedondo. Running this code on my cli php, does it all. The $_GET assignment is for making it run on cli.

Answer (score 0):

Someone answered here, but the answer was deleted ...

The answer was correct, so here it's the solution =>

```
<?
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
function pmUrl($url, $op="+", $val=1)
{
  $pattern = '/[=&][^=&]+-\K\d+(?=&|$)/';
  return preg_replace_callback(
    $pattern,
    function ($m) use ($op, $val) {
      $ret = $op=="+" ? $m[0]+$val : $m[0]-$val;
      return $ret>0 ? $ret : 0;
    },
    $url
  );
}
?>
```

And with this php function, I just have to use =>

```
<?php echo (pmUrl($url, "-", 1)); ?>
```

To generate an url prec (so in my case /index.php?page=wallrank-top10-1&requete=keyword&searchkeyword=pvp)

And

To generate an url next (so in my case /index.php?page=wallrank-top10-3&requete=keyword&searchkeyword=pvp)